# ImproperlyConfigured( django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting REST_FRAMEWORK, environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-settings

I'am getting this error: I cannot see the Filters botton in Filter back ends with URL query parameters.

```
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting REST_FRAMEWORK, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

This my **api_views.py** file:

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

from store.serializers import ProductSerializer
from store.models import Product

class ProductList(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('id',)
```

Here is my **wsgi.py** file:

```
import os
import sys

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
    
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

the **settings.py** file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'django_filters',
    'store',
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend']
}
```

and the **manage.py** code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Can anyone seem to understand the issue here? And if so, can you be so kind as to explain what is wrong?
Thank you!

Filter back ends with URL query parameters to show the Product ID in the browser.

Comment: When/how do you get this error? What action are you performing?

Comment: when the api_views.py file is running I get the above error and when I check the changes in http://127.0.0.1:8000/ server nothing happen.

Comment: Why is the file name `api_views.py` instead of `views.py`?

Comment: I have already a **view.py** file.

Comment: then why are using the `api_view` file?

Comment: It's to show the Product details on my RESTAPI but my problem that come up is that REST_API is not configurated correctly. How can is solve it? There is a way to make a connections between the rest_api and DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE?